# Not able to login using Apple ID

Tags: macos, apple-id

I am trying to login with Apple ID. But it shows an error like in the image. I used to login with a browser and it's working. Also I couldn't update my apps in my Mac. Please help. Not only now... it always shows like this.

[image: Please refer this]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266084/itunes-account-creation-not-allowed-when-trying-to-test-in-app-purchases/40333396) help?

Comment: off topic as it isnt programming related

Comment: One guess might be: you are in a country where iTunes Store is not available.  Perhaps temporarily until your government agrees that Apple has made the restrictions it demands.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

1. Sign out from your Account
2. Just try to download something from iTunes / AppStore
3. iTunes will promt you to sign in
4. Enter your credentials for your account

You're done. Worked for me. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes I tried. But on that time only i got this  popup message. I am from Malaysia

Comment: Well, what about editing your AppleID password and try again?

Comment: I did using the latest password only. If i login in browser i can able to login. If i using to download the app then i came across this issue.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of iTunes installed on your Mac?

Comment: Yes my version is 12.8.0.150

Comment: could you please try to download an app in the MacOS AppStore? Would be interesting to know if that is working.